Unity Error : Manifest Merger failed with multiple error see logs

Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE


Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac


Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests


Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
24 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 15 up-to-date
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
I am trying to build a AR indoor navigation using unity editor : 2022.2.3f1 with AR foundation
